# What is the difference between getWidth/Height() and getMeasuredWidth/Height() in Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, size, dimensions

The [Android Documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SizePaddingMargins) that there is two sizes for a view, the *measured dimensions* and the *drawing dimensions*. The measured dimension is the one computed in the *measure pass* (the [onMeasure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29) method), while the *drawing dimensions* are the actual size on screen. Particularly, the documentation says that:

> These values may, but do not have to, be different from the measured width and height.

So, my question is: what could make the drawing dimension be different of the measured dimension? If the [onMeasure(int,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29) method respects the layout requirements (given as the parameters *widthMeasureSpec* and *heightMeasureSpec*, how could the SDK decides that the view should have a different drawing size?

Additionally, how/where in the [Android Source Code](https://github.com/android) the measured width/height is used to compute the drawing width/height? I tryed to look into the [View source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java), but I can't figure out how the measuredWidth/Height is used to compute the final width/height. Maybe it has something to do with the padding, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think that these measures can be different in case if a scroll is added to the view.

Comment: Maybe, but I developed a custom ViewGroup, and this is happening in my code. I am not dealing with scroll until the point where this behavior occurs. So I think that there should be more than scroll involved into this.

Comment: I confirm, I developer a custom ViewGroup too to force a given aspect-ratio: I forced measured width and height (lower or equal then proposed), but I had as result real width and height not changed (not the measured ones). No relation with scroll. I really cannot find a way to force the real width and height.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

As the name suggests the measuredWidth/height is used during measuring and layoutting phase.

Let me give an example,

A widget is asked to measure itself, The widget says that it wants to be 200px by 200px. This is measuredWidth/height.

During the layout phase, i.e. in onLayout method. The method can use the measuredWidth/height of its children or assign a new width/height by calling layout method of the view.

lets say the onLayout method calls childview.layout(0,0,150,150) now the width/height of the view is different than the measured width/height.

I would suggest not to use the measuredWidth/height outside onLayout method.

to summarize .

1. onMeasure -> sets up measuredWidth/measuredHeight
2. onLayout -> sets up the width/height of the widget.

additionallly
`public void View.layout(int l, int t, int r, int b)`
seems to be place where the assignment of position and size happens.

Comment: that is , we should always use getWidth/getHeight to get the "real" dimension of a View, right?

Comment: Yes, but if you are doing your own layouting then you should use measuredWidth instead of width.

Comment: So, what's the purpose of setting dimesions inside onMeasure()? I mean, the layout pass is the last one, in which you set the final dimensions of the view, possibliy regardless of measured dimensions

Comment: @edoardotognoni it depends upto the layout (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout or your custom layout) , to give the correct size and position to the view.

Comment: Ok let's say the view tells "I'd like these dimensions". While the layout says "You will have these dimensions". Is it right?

Comment: @edoardotognoni yes. But with so many customviews that I have implemented, the measuredwidth being different than width has been rare. But you should avoid using the incorrect width. measuredWidth maynot always be same as width.

Comment: Hi, I am creating a canvas. For the width / height, should I pass in the measured width / height or just say getWidth() / getHeight(). Also, why shouldn't you use measuredWidth / measuredHeight outside of the onLayout() method? Thanks.