# Calling getWidth of parent in onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it ok to get parent's width in `onCreateViewHolder` at RecyclerView adapter? Are parent's dimensions measured at that state so I don't get 0 when I call `getWidth()` on parent?

Comment: Easy path is try it out and see. there are methods getTop, etc for Recycler view that I know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the parent is actually the `RecyclerView`.  It has both a non-zero getWidth() and getMeasuredWidth() by the time onCreateViewHolder is called.

Easy way to verify this is set your debugger to stop in the method and inspect the parent.

```
parent = android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{d08d560 VFED..... ......ID 0,0-1080,1698 #7f0c0074 app:id/recyclerView1}

mMeasuredWidth = 1080
mLeft = 0
mRight = 1080
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a case where I actually got 0 on some occasions when calling `parent.getWidth()`, so I had to use `getMeasuredWidth()`. For anybody facing this issue or wondering about it, I suggest you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657540/what-is-the-difference-between-getwidth-height-and-getmeasuredwidth-height-i#answer-8664581)