# RecyclerView children match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

My problem is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691150/match-parent-width-does-not-work-in-recyclerview), however unlike it's OP I'm passing the `parent` to the `LayoutInflater`. I'm using support library 25.3.1. Here's the layout that I'm inflating (Changing the `ConstraintLayout` to `LinearLayout` doesn't help):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_text_primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.ListPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/list_text_secondary"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:ignore="Deprecated"
        tools:text="list_text_primary"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_text_secondary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.ListSecondary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list_text_primary"
        tools:ignore="Deprecated"
        tools:text="list_text_secondary"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've also tried to set the `LayoutParams` manually in `onCreateViewHolder` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39773413/4061413). I thought it worked but from time to time the `parent` will have a 0 width and height (I'm unable to pinpoint the reason) causing the child to become invisible. [image: debug_screenshot] According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39002034/4061413) the `RecyclerView` should already me measured by the time `onCreateViewHolder` is called.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View in RecyclerView does not match parent width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251626/view-in-recyclerview-does-not-match-parent-width)

Answer (score 0):

If you paste your adapter code, that would have been better, but you can try this.

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Point size = new Point();
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            holder.yourItemBinding.getRoot().setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(size.x,
                    RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Replace

> holder.yourItemBinding.getRoot()

with your root view object if you are not using layout binding.