# Not able to Draw the circle in Custom View android using onDraw(canvas) function?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-custom-view

I am not able to draw the circle using Custom Views in Android. It just doesn't work, even though it is a basic code implementation, it is not working. Can someone help me for the same?

This is Custom View class implementation:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    private Paint paint;
    private int color;
    private float radius;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView);      
        color = ta.getColor(R.styleable.CustomView_circleColor, Color.BLACK);
        radius = ta.getFloat(R.styleable.CustomView_circleSize, 200f);
        ta.recycle();
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, radius, paint);

    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

And this is my MainActivity implementation:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

This is attr.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="circleColor" format="color"></attr>

        <attr name="circleSize" format="enum">

            <enum name="small" value="100"></enum>
            <enum name="medium" value="300"></enum>
            <enum name="large" value="600"></enum>

        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

And this is activity_main.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hp.customviews.MainActivity">

    <com.hp.customviews.CustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:circleColor="#009688"
        app:circleSize="medium"
        android:visibility="gone" />



</FrameLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why my code is not working? Please help me with this.

Comment: Remove the `android:visibility="gone"` attribute from the layout XML, or set it to `"visible"`.

Comment: Thanks, working now. Though can you please tell me the at this time what is my width as with getWidth() and with getmeasurablewidth() ? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Here's a decent summary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8664581.

Comment: Ok, thanks, also can you tell me what is the layout_width and layout_height that I am setting in my custom view in activity_main.xml is it measurable width and height or drawing width or height?