# Programatically scaling and centering imageView given rectangular bounds

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-constraintlayout

**My Problem**

Suppose I have a bitmap - call it `bmap` with dimensions `100x75` (`bmap.getWidth() x bmap.getHeight()`)

Suppose I have a rectangle, `rect`, sitting at point on the phone screen (x,y), with dimensions `500x350` (`width x height`)

How might I write a piece of code, which centers this bitmap within the bounding rect.

Note: Because I am using `ContraintLayout` there is not concept of parents or relativity.

Additionally, I would like a `scale` variable in the range `(0,1]`, which scales `bmap` but it maintains its position in the center of the bounding rectangle `rect`.

**My horrible attempt:**

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this.context);
imgView.setMaxWidth((int)(width*scale));
imgView.setMinimumWidth((int)(width*scale));
imgView.setMaxHeight((int)(height*scale));
imgView.setMinimumHeight((int)(height*scale));

imgView.setImageBitmap(bmap);

imgView.setX(x+((width-bmap.getWidth())/2));
imgView.setY(y+((height-bmap.getHeight())/2));

imgView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

constraintLayout.addView(imgView);
```

This gives the following result (with `scale = 1` for the green circle and `scale = 0.6` for the red circle

[image]

Any ideas? I'm really stuck.

Comment: Are the circles and rectangles both inside the ConstraintLayout?

Comment: How and when do you get your width, height, x and y values?

Comment: Circle and rectangle are both in the ConstraintLayout. Width and Height are obtained from the rectangle. x and y are obtained from the rectangle

Comment: Ive never done this before, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I see for this problem is to use the containers provided by android to help us to get this behavior. First of all, you can use relative layouts inside an constraint layout. there is no problem with that. Use two relative layouts with an image view inside them an just us centerInParent property to do the trick. I strongly recomend don't resize programatically the size of the views. Use the containers and the tools you have.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the grey rectangles are normal Android `Views` which are children of your `ConstraintLayout`. They are created and added programmatically, so you'll have to give them ids with `setId()` method. The `ids` have to be positive numbers and have to be unique in this view hierarchy.

The size of the images which you are going to center in them is not important. You just have to give them proper constraints.

```
    //Set the id for the greyRectangleLeft
    greyRectangleLeft.setId(1)
    //Create a new constraint set
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    //Clone the current constraints from your ConstraintsLayout to avoid losing them
    set.clone(constraintLayout);

    //Create the ImageView and set its Bitmap
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmap);
    //The imageView should have an id as well
    imageView.setId(2);

    //Add the constraints which will center the ImageView within the bounds of the grey_rectangle_left
    set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, greyRectangleLeft.getId(), ConstraintSet.START);
    set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, greyRectangleLeft.getId(), ConstraintSet.END);
    set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, greyRectangleLeft.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
    set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, greyRectangleLeft.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

    //Set the width and height of your ImageView to the desired width and height
    set.constrainWidth(imageView.getId(), bmap.getWidth());
    set.constrainHeight(imageView.getId(), bmap.getHeight());

    //Add the newly created ImageView to the ConstraintLayout
    constraintLayout.addView(imageView);
    //Apply the created constraints
    set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Repeat for the `greyRectangleRight` and second `ImageView` (but give them different ids).

Regarding the scale, I recommend using [setScaleX()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX(float)) and [setScaleY()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleY(float)) of the `ImageViews`.

Comment: Grey rectangle is programatically created, does not have an ID

Comment: So use greyRectangle.getId() instead of R.id.grey_rectangle when calling set.connect().

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot

Comment: Check the edited answer, you'll have to set the ids for your `ImageViews` and `greyRectangles` to let the `ConstraintLayout` work correctly.

Let me know if it didn't work - I've created a sample project and it seems to be centered as you wanted. I'll share the code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually does do what you expect it to do, but you probably use `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` instead of `getMeasuredHeight()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`. This will result in getting the width and height that are calculated from the xml and not the measured width and height that are set after the layout phase.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657540/what-is-the-difference-between-getwidth-height-and-getmeasuredwidth-height-i) to learn more about the difference between them.

Comment: getWidth and getHeight comes from the bitmap, not the imageView

Comment: @GregPeckory When I write getWidth() and getHeight() I'm talking about how you obtain the values for width and height variables. The way I interpreted your description was that they came from the gray rectangle views.